# Launching RDP (mstsc.exe) with a supplied IP without autoconnecting

Tags: rdp, mstsc

I am creating a program (in C#, .net 4) that allows the user to highlight an IP address from a textbox and click a button that launches RDP (MSTSC.EXE) supplied with the highlighted IP.  What I'd like to do is NOT have RDP try to auto-connect to the IP (which is what happens if you provide the -v: argument).  Rather, bring up the usual RDP dialog that will allow the user to either edit the IP or click "Connect" to go ahead and connect.

Is this possible?  There doesn't appear to be any command line switch that prevents autoconnecting.  The only thing I can think of is to create an .RDP file with the IP and then use the -edit switch.  Although I'm wondering if it's possible to launch mstsc.exe and then do some kind of Clipboard paste to paste the IP into mstsc.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after rewording my question.

SendKeys.SendWait("^V") did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[To avoid reconnection see this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323258)

For the rest use

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {


        static void Main()
        {
            // Get the path that stores favorite links.
           Process.Start("mstsc.exe", "/v:10.58.45.24"); //Or whatever 

        }
    }
}
```